# Uploading image as BLOB with parameters - iOS to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ios, blob

I'm trying to upload an image as a BLOB type and insert it into a MySQL database using queries. I have been breaking my head on this code below.
ID is the string and imagedata is the UIImage content converted as NSData.

```
    NSString *urlToUpload = [[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:IP] stringByAppendingString:@":8888/uploadBlob.php"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToUpload]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



    /*
     Set Header and content type of your request.
     */
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------Boundary Line---------------------------";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    NSString *fileName = [processID stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];

    /*
     now lets create the body of the request.
     */
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];


     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"ID"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[processID urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set body with request.
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSData *returnData1 =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Here is the PHP script that receives these values:

```
  <?php
   $DB_hostname = "localhost";
   $DB_Name = "root";
   $DB_pass = "pass123";


   $target_path = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
   $id = $_POST['ID'];
   $image = file_get_contents($target_path);





   $con = mysql_connect($DB_Hostname,$DB_Name,$DB_pass) or die(mysql_error());

   //echo "test";
   mysql_select_db("arcadia_aex", $con);

   $sql = "UPDATE vessel_wms_out SET PicFile = '". mysql_real_escape_string($image) ."' WHERE WDRAW_NO = '$id' ";

   $res = mysql_query($sql);

   if ($res) {
        echo "image stored as blob".$id ;
   }else{ 
        echo "blob storage failed";
   }

   mysql_close($con);

   ?>
```

Anyidea where im going wrong in this?

Comment: A database is NOT made for storing binary image data. Save the image as file and only some relevant data into the database (like path, filename, size ...)

Comment: im saving the image as BLOB type. Thats the table structure. So im passing the image as data

Comment: Yeah, but you should not store them in the database in whatever format ;)

Comment: ok I totally agree with your idea! now my client wants it that way. It worked for the android version. So I HAVE TO set it up for iOS as well.

Comment: any solutions found yet?